# Mapping nested values with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code where I use ng-repeat to loop and map some json values, `rows` is the json data where `columns` matches the key I want to display:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.rows = [{"name": "tom","date": "now"}, {"name": "jack","date": "now"}]; 
    angular.toJson($scope.rows);

    $scope.columns = [{"title":"Title","field":"name"},{"title":"Date","field":"date"}];


}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="row in rows">

        <div ng-repeat="column in columns">

            {{row[column.field]}}


        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dakra/U3pVM/

My problem is: How can I display/represent nested values. This is what I want to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/GCSHA/10/ where I get the company name using `user.company`.

For example:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.rows = [{"name": "tom", "user": {"company": "test"}}]

    $scope.columns = [{"title":"Title","field":"name"},{"title":"Company","field":"user.company"}];


}
```

So in the above example the excepted output is:

```
Tom
Test
```

Comment: What is expected output? There is no need of nesting `ng-repeats`, just combine the data and repeat once on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it done with small utility method to read properties repeatedly.

Something like this :

```
$scope.readProperty = function(obj, prop) {
            var newObj = obj;
    var props = prop.split('.');
    for(var i = 0; i<props.length; i++) {
            newObj = newObj[props[i]];
    }
    return newObj;

}
```

Working example here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/GCSHA/12/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `{{row[column.field]}}` converts to `{{row[user.company"]}}`. This is incorrect. It should be `{{row[user][company]"]}}`

Comment: So you would need to split the ``user.company`` i.e. find the dot ``.``?

Comment: Yes, as specified by Nils.